# Is it possible to store form data briefly in a modal button?

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, modal-dialog

Basically I want to know if it's at all possible to store the data inputted from a modal's form for future use in the page where the button that initiated the modal is without using a database ?

I want this so I process all the data from the inputs on the main page and the one's from the modal at the same time.

Comment: You could store data in local JS vars if you are not going to reload the page. If you want to reload the pages between requests then you will need to store in cookies or pass the data to the backend to be stored in the users session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible by storing cookies and accessing them when the user logs on the respective page.

Comment: But doesn't the website require permission from the user to use cookies? If so I'd like a way that does not involve them.